# is there a solution to resize 3d data Without the data become messy?

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, resize, nifti

i use this code to resize 3d nifti data  but when i check the result i found it messy and the axes are changed

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
import itertools

initial_size_x = 560
initial_size_y = 560
initial_size_z = 240

new_size_x = 512
new_size_y = 512
new_size_z = 216

initial_data = nib.load("id001-512x512x216.nii.gz-pred.nii").get_data()
print('helooooooooooooooooooo')
delta_x = initial_size_x/new_size_x
delta_y = initial_size_y/new_size_y
delta_z = initial_size_z/new_size_z

new_data = np.zeros((new_size_x,new_size_y,new_size_z))

for x, y, z in itertools.product(range(new_size_x),
                                 range(new_size_y),
                                 range(new_size_z)):
    new_data[x][y][z] = initial_data[int(x*delta_x)][int(y*delta_y)][int(z*delta_z)]

img = nib.Nifti1Image(new_data, np.eye(4))
img.to_filename("test_"+str(new_size_x)+""+str(new_size_y)+""+str(new_size_z)+".nii")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQnJp.png)

Comment: Have you tried `np.repeat`?

Comment: @taless no how i can use it!!

Answer (score 1):

In this question, I believe you want to slightly change the resolution of 3D data. The solution I am presenting only works for enlarging or shrinking the data an integer number of times.

For enlarging the data, you can use `np.repeat` and for shrinking it you can use slicing. For example, here we can write:

```py
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
import itertools

initial_size_x = 560
initial_size_y = 560
initial_size_z = 240

new_size_x = 1120
new_size_y = 1120
new_size_z = 720

initial_data = nib.load("id001-512x512x216.nii.gz-pred.nii").get_data()

rep_x = new_size_x/initial_size_x # 2
rep_y = new_size_y/initial_size_y # 2
rep_z = new_size_z/initial_size_z # 3

new_data = np.repeat(initial_data, rep_x, axis=0)
new_data = np.repeat(new_data, rep_y, axis=1)
new_data = np.repeat(new_data, rep_z, axis=2)
```

### Possible improvements

I am sure this answer can be improved. However I am not sure what you have in mind from a floating point repetition.

For instance, should `my_repeat(data, 0.9, axis=axis)` skip every 10th element?